# Attempt at combining Bitflags in C# enum

Tags: c#, enums

```
public enum EFlagsBmp
{
    None = 0,
    A = (1 << 0),  //1
    B = (1 << 1),  //2
    C = (1 << 2),  //4 
    D = (1 << 3), //8
    E = (1 << 4),  //16
    F = (1 << 5),  //32
    G = (1 << 6),
    H = (1 << 7),
    I = (1 << 8),
    J = (1 << 9),
    K = (1 << 10),
    L = (1 << 11),
    SB1 = (1 << 12),
    SB2 = (1 << 13),
    TR1 = ~(SB1) & ~(SB2),   // BIT12 - 0   BIT13 - 0
    TR2 = (SB1) & ~(SB2),    // BIT12 - 1   BIT13 - 0 
    TR3 = ~(SB1) & (SB2),    // BIT12 - 0   BIT13 - 1
    TR4 = (SB1) | (SB2),     // BIT12 - 1   BIT13 - 1
    VSB = (1 << 18),
}
```

Here I have attempted to combine bitflags (`BIT12` and `BIT13`) as below.

```
SB1 = (1 << 12),
SB2 = (1 << 13),
TR1 = ~(SB1) & ~(SB2),   // BIT12 - 0   BIT13 - 0
TR2 = (SB1) & ~(SB2),    // BIT12 - 1   BIT13 - 0 
TR3 = ~(SB1) & (SB2),    // BIT12 - 0   BIT13 - 1
TR4 = (SB1) | (SB2),     // BIT12 - 1   BIT13 - 1
```

I want to be able to set as well as read back the following configurations

`TR1`
`TR2`
`TR3`
`TR4`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your bitwise code is incorrect.

Assume A = 0001
Assume B = 0010

A is first bit is set, B is 2nd bit is set

x & ~A doesn't mean what you think. ~A doesn't mean first bit is off, it means 1110. So x & ~A would only be true if those 3 bits are set, not just if the first bit is off.

If you want A is not set, that's ((x & A) == 0). Or if you want cleaner code, use the [Flags] modifier on the enum and then you get Enum.HasFlag().

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about what you're *trying* to do with the flags. Flags are usually not exclusive settings; they're used in combination. So let's examine your logic:

For `TR1`

```
TR1 = ~(SB1) & ~(SB2),   // BIT12 - 0   BIT13 - 0
```

The result of which is:

```
0011111111111
```

Note that this has turned on every flag *except* `SB1` and `SB2`. Setting one flag should *not* affect others.

What you're really trying to do is check which flags have been set. For this, you should have either helper methods, or use `Enum.HasFlag`. It should *not* be baked into the `enum` itself, as it's impossible to represent `SB1 & !SB2` as a set of bits, while also treating them as flags.

Thus, you should have:

```
[Flags]
public enum EFlagsBmp 
{
    ...
}

public static class EFlagsBmpHelper
{
    public static bool TR1(this EFlagsBmp flags)
    {
        return !flags.HasFlag(EFlagsBmp.SB1) && !flags.HasFlag(EFlagsBmp.SB2);
    }
    public static bool TR2(this EFlagsBmp flags)
    {
        return flags.HasFlag(EFlagsBmp.SB1) && !flags.HasFlag(EFlagsBmp.SB2);
    }
    public static bool TR3(this EFlagsBmp flags)
    {
        return !flags.HasFlag(EFlagsBmp.SB1) && flags.HasFlag(EFlagsBmp.SB2);
    }
    public static bool TR4(this EFlagsBmp flags)
    {
        return flags.HasFlag(EFlagsBmp.SB1) && flags.HasFlag(EFlagsBmp.SB2);
    }
}
```

Which you can then use as:

```
EFlagsBmp.K.TR1()
```

Comment: I want to be able to set the above four cases as well. `HasFlag` only checks if the flag has been set right?

Comment: @liv2hak That's correct. So `HasFlag(A)` would return true if the value were `A | B`